# Condition for files without an extension and or also looking at the file name - Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I am currently writing a program where files will be split. However, I am still learning at the moment. My code will look at files with extensions but there are files that would be flat flies as well. If the users enter only the filename without an extension it should also split it because the user entered the filename. I wrote the code below but it seems not to be working with only the file name. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. The code will also have to look only at the filename without the need of an extension.

```
input_entity = sys.argv[1]
input_date = sys.argv[2]

if input_entity.endswith(".csv") or input_entity.endswith(".txt") or input_entity:
        print("Processing file:", input_entity)
        process_file(input_entity, input_date, input_entity)
    else:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(input_entity):
            for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt") or f.endswith(".csv") or filesnames]:
                #print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                print("Processing file:", filename)
                process_file(file_path, input_date, filename)
            break
```

Comment: You have a typo: `for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt") or f.endswith(".csv") or filesnames]:` the typo being `filesnames` at the end. Also, your indentation is incorrect, though I assume that is due to the question editor and not your actual code.

Comment: Also, your initial `if` statement is a bit pointless. It will *always* evaluate true if `sys.argv[1]` is present due to `or input_entity` so why check for file extension too?